# An alternative definition of polymorphism

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, overriding

I'm writing you to be sure that I really understood the definition of polymorphism.
So, if I write:

```
SuperClass sc=new SubClass();
```

Is it like saying "I'd like an object of class SuperClass, but I want it to behave like a Subclass object for the overriden methods"?
Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 3):

I do not interpret it exactly like that. I would say: "I want a SubClass object but it should be treated as a SuperClass so that it does not matter which exactly sub-class it is."

That is, imagine you have SubClass1 and SubClass2 implementing both implementing the method calculate, you want to be able to call the method for all of them without knowing exactly which class they are, you just treat all of them as SuperClass.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to understand, I think, by being specific. Consider:

```
Pet myPet = new Dog();
```

versus:

```
Pet myPet = new Cat();
```

What's the difference? If all you know about your pet is that it is a `Pet`, then you don't know what will happen exactly if you call:

```
myPet.beHappy();
```

In the first case, `beHappy()` might be implemented as `this.wagTail();`, while in the second case, it might be `this.purr();`.

Now go back to your initial description and substitute the specific classes: *"I'd like a Pet, but I want it to behave like a Dog [or Cat] for being happy".* Whether this is an accurate description of what's happening depends, I think, on your perspective. Certainly, you do, in fact, have a `Pet` object that behaves like a `Dog` (or `Cat`) object. On the other hand, one might as well have said: *"I'd like a Dog, but I want to interact with it like I would with any other Pet."* This is also a valid description of what's going on.

Which is the right description? They both are. Which is preferable? It simply depends on which side of the assignment statement you are starting from.

Answer (score 1):

i think your understanding is right.

> The dictionary definition of polymorphism refers to a principle in
>   biology in which an organism or species can have many different forms
>   or stages. This principle can also be applied to object-oriented
>   programming and languages like the Java language. Subclasses of a
>   class can define their own unique behaviors and yet share some of the
>   same functionality of the parent class.

from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 0):

I like using the idea of Shapes.  "All triangles are shapes, but not all shapes are triangles."  All triangles behave like shapes, but not all shapes behave like triangles.

For example, all shapes have an area, but this is not calculated the same way.  Circles (the subclass or the superclass Shape), use the formula phi*r*r, but this won't work for all shapes (i.e. not all Shapes are Circles).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not correct. This way you are creating an object of `SubClass`, although you cannot refer to methods that are specifically of `SubClass`, but only to the methods of class `SuperClass`, because `sc` is of `SuperClass` type. If you override some methods in `SubClass`, the actual `SubClass` code will be executed, regardless of the fact that your object is declared as `SuperClass`.

Main difference is between compile time type, and run time type. In this case, `sc` is of `SuperClass` type at compile time, but at run time it is of `SubClass` (that would mean of course that if you don't override methods in `SubClass` the respective methods of `SuperClass` will be executed if invoked).

Answer (score 0):

Your statement: "I'd like an object of class SuperClass, but I want it to behave like a Subclass object for the overriden methods" is correct, and it is [Sub-type polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism)

You can also have polymorphism which implements an interface.  One common example is the toString() method, where each class has a similar behavior (printing as a String)

See [Polymorphism in OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) at Wikipedia for another example.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a subclass reference into a super class variable and modifying the behavior so that any call on the superclass will invoke the subclass methods. Polymorphism can be achieved through overloading or overriding. Hope these example links below clarify more.

[Example One](http://www.harford.edu/faculty/FBrundick/cis214/programs/polymorph.html)

[Second example](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091118135506AAQboUd)